# Set Notification Icon in Gnome Shell >= 3.16 (Custom Extension)

Tags: javascript, gnome, gnome-shell, gjs

I've forked a Gnome Shell Extension, as I want to modify it to fit my personal preferences. I want to send a notification each time an event occurs. Sending the notification itself is fairly easy with `Main.notify(summary, text)`. However, I just can't find out how to set a custom icon. [EDIT: The following is wrong. I looked up bad code]<s>According to the github repo of gnome-shell I can define an icon via an optional parameter: `Main.notify(summary, text, params)`, where `params` will be checked in `MessageTray.js l.367:`</s>

```
params = Params.parse(params, { gicon: null,
                                secondaryGIcon: null,
                                bannerMarkup: false,
                                clear: false,
                                soundName: null,
                                soundFile: null });

if (params.gicon || params.clear)
    this.gicon = params.gicon;
```

So I tried to use the following command:

```
Main.notify(summary, text, {gicon: myicon});
```

But the `{gicon: myicon}` part is ignored completely and the default icon is used :-/.
I'm new to Javascript and GNOME programming, so pls don't hate me :-)

Is using `Main.notify()` recommended generally, or is it deprecated?

Cheers, Maphardam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that `Main.notify()` is generally recommended, as it is used in some of the *"official"* extensions.

However, `Main.notify()` only takes two parameters `(msg, details)` and thus you cannot use this function to set a custom icon.
You can however copy the source of `Main.notify()` and adapt it to your own needs. Inside the following function the `source` of the notification is set to a newly created source with a custom icon.

```
function notify(msg, details, icon) {
    let source = new MessageTray.Source("MyApp Information", icon);
    Main.messageTray.add(source);
    let notification = new MessageTray.Notification(source, msg, details);
    notification.setTransient(true);
    source.notify(notification);
}
```

For example you could call it with `notify("MyApp", "Test", 'folder-symbolic');`.

Comment: Ah, so the icon information is set in the `source` variable. Thanks, that's what I missed.

Comment: You can also use a completely custom GIcon like this: `let notification = new MessageTray.Notification(source, msg, details, {gicon: my_g_icon});`. Documentation: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/blob/master/js/ui/messageTray.js#L298

Comment: `JS ERROR: Error: Expected type string for argument 'property_name' but got type GObject_Object`, error point to `source.notify(notification);` line.

Comment: the last line change to `source.showNotification(notification);` then works.